# Dissolving using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, dissolve, pyqgis-3

I have trouble to use function dissolve to dissolve polygons by field value in PyQGIS3. 
In PyQGIS2 this line was doing the job:

```
QgsGeometryAnalyzer().dissolve(ki, "name.shp", onlySelectedFeatures=False,uniqueIdField=-1, p=None)
```

I read on this site that processing alg should be use in PyQGIS3. But I can't find [here](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.4/) disolve. When I run `processing.algorithmHelp("native:dissolve")` I can't get the list of attributes, I just get some basic information. So I don't know how to use it.

Comment: The easiest approach is to run the algorithm through the GUI, and then look in the Processing "history". You'll see the equivalent Python command shown there for the operation you just performed via the gui.

Comment: Thank you men, I dont know how I didnt see that before. Please write your comment as an answer and I will approve

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest approach is to run the algorithm through the GUI, and then look in the Processing "history". You'll see the equivalent Python command shown there for the operation you just performed via the gui.